# Improvement on execution time from an aplication done with multi-threading is limited by the number of physical cores?

Tags: multithreading

I was doing some testing with multi-threading on a linux virtual machine, and I implemented a benchmark with 10 threads (in this application each instruction would be executed 10x times more than in the single-thread scenario) and i was tweaking with the number of "physical cores" from the VM settings and with the single thread case I obtain 3s on average independently of the number of physical cores, If the number of cores is set to 1, and I run the multi-thread version, the execution time will be 30s. If I run it with 2 cores I obtain 15s and with 8 cores (the maximum number I can set) I obtain 6s, I obtain this dependancy due to the fact that I´m executing 10x times each instruction or is always like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have *N* threads running on *N* cores, and if they are all doing pure computation (i.e., not waiting for any I/O devices), and if they are all completely independent of each other, then they should be able to do *N* times as much work in a given amount of time as a single thread can do in the same amount of time.

But, that's if they are *completely* independent. That's a hard thing to achieve. For example, if the threads can't each do all of their work in their own, independent cache (e.g., in L1 cache,) then they will compete with each other for access to the main memory. They will sometimes have to wait for one another, because only one core can access main memory at any given moment.  So, if the threads need to use memory, then the speedup will be somewhat less than *N* times.

If the threads need to *share* data in main memory, then it gets worse because then they will need to use mutual exclusion locks. One thread may keep a lock locked while it executes dozens of instructions, and any other thread that wants the same lock will have to wait until it is finished.

If the threads need to synchronize with each other/communicate with each other, then it gets worse still because unless their work loads are carefully balanced, a thread with less work to do may spend *long* periods of time awaiting signals from threads that have more work to do.

It's not unusual for a novice programmer to invent a multi-threaded version of some single-threaded algorithm, and find out that the multi-threaded version actually is *slower* than the single-threaded version.

There are *some* algorithms, for which even an expert programmer can't get much speed up by throwing more threads at it.